# Why minted package hangs up compilation?

Tags: minted

Why pdflatex hangs up

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
Assembler translates
\begin{minted}{mips}
    addu $t5, $t1, $t2
\end{minted}
into binary code:
\end{document}
```

with this document?

I already ran the command with shell escape, and non stop mode for interaction:

```bash
pdflatex -synctex=1 --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode CMPE325.tex
```

and straight up hangs on

```bash
[4] (./_minted-CMPE325/default.pygstyle) (./_minted-CMPE325/9F3E4DE4F320346FC38F0B9A9835A5296F866F5A1B946E33CB8EBBACAEBD804E.pygtex (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/inconsolata/t1zi4.fd)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/zi4/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/zi4/m/n' instead on input line 2.

)
```

No more output after this. It just hangs.

I am running pdflatex M2 Macbook Pro so 3 lines of LaTeX code shouldnt cause a memory or CPU issue.

I dont think rest of the document is irrelevant, but I can send the full document if needed. not like, it is top confidential or something, just some dumb lecture notes.

Comment: I am very sh*t at explaining myself, but I will try to.

Comment: Alright, tried to explain myself in words @DavidCarlisle

Comment: The code posted can't give that font warning, what is selecting zi4 font family?

Comment: Your example produces `Error: no lexer for alias 'mips' found` when I tried it. Are you using a nonstandard lexer, or just have a newer pygments?

Comment: the log you show is showing an error on page 4, please show the log from the code as posted, so we can compare.

Comment: Using newer pygments, i dont have any mips.sty in sight. Latest version of  pygmentise at the moment. I am using Inconsolata, so probably why it is giving zi4 font family warning? Page 4 corresponds to the code I sent, if I remove this minted code segment it is all fine, I can compile it normally. Problematic part is the minted segment in the post. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: No the code you sent only makes one page, please show the log from the posted code, does that hang at all?

Comment: Yes it does, it hangs after [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (./_minted-CMPE325/default.pygstyle) line in the output. After that zero output. And just informational output like programming layer, document class, loaded modules yada yada at the beginning. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: if you change mips to asm does it fail (as I have that lexer)

Comment: Yes it does, hangs with same output @DavidCarlisle

Comment: hmm I GET ) (./_minted-ee264/default.pygstyle)
(./_minted-ee264/B8C12D07497BA5E6E8F0590FA96CF63E550570FC90E586AB22730DC8AF2AB4
4C.pygtex) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.
map}] (./ee264.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/ams
fonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfo
nts/cm/cmtt12.pfb>
Output written on ee264.pdf (1 page, 16566 bytes).
Transcript written on ee264.log.

real    0m3.821s
user    0m1.684s
sys     0m2.102s

Comment: Yeah I cant get past the default.pygstyle. interestingly.

Comment: I give up, it may be a mac issue, wait a bit I'm sure a mac user will pass by and confirm if your example works for them, sorry can't help more

Comment: Thanks anyways for your effort mate! cheers, @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Works for me on a Mac with `Pygments version 2.16.1` and `Python 3.11.6`. Of course I don't get Inconsolata as your error message hints at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue with deleting Homebrew version of Pygments, creating new Python venv, downloading Pygments from pip instead, and run the command in the venv. Thanks to @egreg for pointing me to right direction.